# Variable undefined after 2nd call

Tags: javascript

In the 1st function 'get_files()' I can log the file_list variable, it is correct here, however when I log it again in my 2nd function 'get_diffs()' it is undefined..

```
// Get files
async function get_files() {
    await fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, files) {
        (async () => {
            if (await err) {
                console.log("Error getting directory information.", err)
            } else {
                var file_list = []; // Reset
                await files.forEach(function (file) {
                    file_list.push(file);
                });
                console.log('1st Call =  ' + file_list);  // Correct
                return await file_list;
            }
        })();
    });
}

// Get Diffs
async function get_diffs() {
    const file_list = await get_files();
    console.log('2nd Call =  ' + file_list); // Undefined
    const dates = await get_dates();
    return await files.filter(x => !dates.includes(x));
}
```

Comment: You are missing the correct use of `await` and `async`... Like `await err`: that makes no sense. But it is just one of the many problems in your code.

Comment: the await is unnessacery in numerous parts, eg in the foreach and next to the return and in the start next to readdir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood async/await. Learn the basics [here](https://javascript.info/async-await)

```js
function get_files() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readdir(dirPath, function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var file_list = []; // Reset
                files.forEach(function (file) {
                    file_list.push(file);
                });
                console.log('1st Call =  ' + file_list);  // Correct
                resolve(file_list);
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readdir` does not return a promise. Use the promise based function `fs.promise.readdir` instead.

```
async function get_diffs() {
    const file_list = await fs.promise.readdir(dirPath);
    // ...
}
```

So you don't really need the other function. It had many problems anyway. `await` makes not much sense when used with an expression that is not a promise.    All the places where you have used `await` in `get_files`, the expression that follows it does not represent a promise.